# Is there a name for this generalized assignment problem variant with an additional indicator constraint

Tags: optimization

I have an optimization problem that's closely related to the generalized assignment problem with an additional constraint. Each knapsack $i$ has capacity $b^i$. There is a number of tasks $j$, each has a cost $c_{i,j}$ and a weight $w_{i,j}$ when assigned t knapsack $i$. The problem is to find an assignment $A^*$ such that the total cost is minimized while each knapsack's capacity is not exceeded by the items' weights. Given that the set of tasks are partitioned into a finite number of non overlapping $l$ groups (i.e., a group of tasks constitutes a job). The additional constraint is as follows: the assignment $A^*$ has a predefined integer $\beta$ of fully assigned groups of tasks: $\sum_{\forall l }\sum_{\forall j} 1_{A*}(x_{i,j}) = \beta$. I am well aware of the classic GAP and heuristics for it. Is there a name for this type of variant of GAP? What are some good resources to go about solving the problem with the additional indicator constraint?

P.S.: I am able to generate the exact solution, I am looking for good resources for approxaimations/heuristics